# Real time countdown on powerpoint slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013, timer

I have to do a presentation soon and it has to be around 15 minutes. To keep track of time (and not look at my watch all the time) I'd like to add a countdown of 15 minutes to my powerpoint presentation for my viewers and myself.

The countdown must start at click from first slide, and then must be visible on all following slides.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: The best way is to **practice your presentation**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea: You have to insert a 15 minutes countdown video into your presentation and set it to play across all your slides.

**1st: Make the video**

You can do this with PowerPoint. Create 15 slides with text on each slide, like: "15:00", "14:00", "13:00". Go to the "*Transitions*" tab and below "*Advance slide*" check "*After*" and set it to 1 minute. Press "*Apply to all*" to apply the time setting for all the slides. So basically you have now a presentation with 15 slides that will change after 1 minute. The only thing left is to save it as a .wmv file (video). Go to *File->Save As..-> and select to save as .wmv* .

**2nd: Inserting the countdown in your presentation**

- Open your PowerPoint presentation.
- Go to "*Insert-> Video-> Video from file...*" and select your countdown video
- Scale your video and place it where you think it won't disturb the presentation.
- Select the Video and go to "*Animations*-> select the "*Play*" animation -> select "*Start on click*"
- Click "*Animation Pane*" to open it and there right click on your video's animation and select "*Effect options...*"
- Under "*Stop playing*" select "*After*" and set the number of slides of your presentation.

[image]